# Updating a property of an object using LINQ when value needed is from db

Tags: c#, linq

How do you suppose I tackle this? Basically, I have this inital query:

```
var orders = (from order in _dbContext.Orders
                  join orderDetail in _dbContext.OrderDetails on order.ID equals orderDetail.OrderID                                      
                  where order.StoreID == storeID
                  select new Order
                  {
                      ID = order.ID,                                          
                      No = order.ID,
                      Type = "",       // Notice that this is empty; this one needs updating
                      Quantity = order.Quantity,

                      // more properties here

                  }).AsQueryable();
```

After this query, I need to loop through the result and update the Type property based on different criteria like this:

```
string type = "";
foreach (OrderDetailDto order in orders)
{
if (order.UserID != null)
    type = "UserOrder";
else if (order.UserID == null)
    type = "NonUserOrder";
else if (order.Cook == null && (order.Option == "fiery"))
    type = "FieryCook";
else if (check if this has corresponding records in another table) // this part I don't know how to effectively tackle
    type = "XXX";

// Update.
order.Type = type;
}
```

The problem is one of my criteria needs me to check if there are existing record in the database. I would use JOIN but if I have to loop thru several hundreds or thousands of records and then JOIN each one of them then check on db just to get one value, I think that would be very slow.

I can't do the JOIN on the initial query because I might do a different JOIN based on a different criterion. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just join all the lookup tables you might possibly need in left join type way:

```
from o in Orders 
from c in Cooks.Where(x => x.OrderId == m.OrderId).DefaultIfEmpty()
from u in Users.Where(x => x.OrderId == o.OrderId).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new 
{
    Order = m,
    Cook = c,
    User = u
}
```

or depending on your usage patterns you could build the required tables into local Lookups or Dictionaries for linear time searching thereafter:

```
var userDict = Users.ToDictionary(x => x.UserId);
var userIdDict = Users.Select(x => x.UserId).ToDictionary(x => x);
var cooksLookup = Cooks.ToLookup(x => x.Salary);
```